fonts I try look bad
When I use a font that is not Ubuntu regular, they look blurry, specially in the ui parts of chrome.
You can see for example Roboto, which is known for good rendering compatibility.
It looks bad in the system.
It looks worse in chrome tabs.
I've tried other 'simple and effective' fonts, like open sans, droid sans, source sans...nothing better. Letters look too cramped together or too separated and not neat.
Is there anything I can do to improve it in general or just in this part?
Do you know fonts with better font rendering?
Details:
Ubuntu 23.10
thinkpad t480
monitor: 1920x1080 ips 22inch



BTW Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) reaches End of Life on July 11, 2024. After that date this site can not support it. Just a friendly reminder that you may want to upgrade soon. It becomes more complex to upgrade after a release has past EOL.
